# Error decreases on train set but stop to decrease in test set (NN) what is the diagnostic? Treatment?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am relatively new in Neural Network and Keras. I am trying different Neural Network architectures and my goal is not to get the best accuracy but more to understand and be able to diagnostic the problem of my Neural Network.

I am currently doing a time Series Neural Network with 3 different inputs and 3 output. My architecture is:

[Neural Network Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hijwa.png)

I am aware that it is not the best architecture and the results are relatively disappointing:

[Results train/test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8LOp.png)

I know that the architecture might be too complexe for such a simple prediction. However I wonder if there is an explanation about why the error decreases in the train set (loss) but after a couple of epochs it stops to decrease in the test set (val_loss). Is there something else that I could do **except** changing the architecture?

For example:

- Changing function (Relu, Tanh)
- Number of Nodes
- Adding regularisation
- Changing the Batch
- Changing the layers (CCN, LSTM, RNN)
- Other?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: For time series prediction, we have to use a single RNN/LSTM cell. Keep the number of timesteps = 3 for the LSTM/RNN.

Comment: I have one LSTM at the really beginning of the NN with 30 time steps